# How do I get the whole content between two xml tags in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I try to get the whole content between an opening xml tag and it's closing counterpart.

Getting the content in straight cases like `title` below is easy, but how can I get the **whole content** between the tags if *mixed-content* is used and I want to **preserve the inner tags**?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<review>
  <title>Some testing stuff</title>
  <text sometimes="attribute">Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.
  It spans <sometag>multiple lines: <tag>one</tag>, <tag>two</tag> 
  or more</sometag>.</text>
</review>
```

What I want is the content between the two **`text`** tags, including any tags: `Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it. It spans <sometag>multiple lines: <tag>one</tag>, <tag>two</tag> or more</sometag>.`

For now I use regular expressions but it get's kinda messy and I don't like this approach. I lean towards a XML parser based solution. I looked over `minidom`, `etree`, `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup` but couldn't find a solution for this case (whole content, including inner tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree
t = etree.XML(
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<review>
  <title>Some testing stuff</title>
  <text>Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>
</review>"""
)
(t.text + ''.join(map(etree.tostring, t))).strip()
```

The trick here is that `t` is iterable, and when iterated, yields all child nodes. Because etree avoids text nodes, you also need to recover the text before the first child tag, with `t.text`.

```
In [50]: (t.text + ''.join(map(etree.tostring, t))).strip()
Out[50]: '<title>Some testing stuff</title>\n  <text>Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>'
```

Or:

```
In [6]: e = t.xpath('//text')[0]

In [7]: (e.text + ''.join(map(etree.tostring, e))).strip()
Out[7]: 'Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.'
```

Comment: The OP wants to get the content of a specific element. Your solution does not work in this case, at least not directly. I I get an element with `e = t.xpath('//text')[0]` and tried it (`''.join(map(etree.tostring, e))`) but the result was `'<extradata>data</extradata> in it.'`.

Comment: Need to test on some more cases, but your last example works fine for me (so far). When using `find` instead of `xpath` it works with the standard ``etree`` too.

Answer (score 7):

Here's something that works for me and your sample:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<review>
  <title>Some testing stuff</title>
  <text>Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>
</review>"""
)

def flatten(seq):
  r = []
  for item in seq:
    if isinstance(item,(str,unicode)):
      r.append(unicode(item))
    elif isinstance(item,(etree._Element,)):
      r.append(etree.tostring(item,with_tail=False))
  return u"".join(r)

print flatten(doc.xpath('/review/text/node()'))
```

Yields:

```
Some text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.
```

The xpath selects all child nodes of the `<text>` element and either renders them to unicode directly if they are a string/unicode subclass (`<class 'lxml.etree._ElementStringResult'>`) or calls `etree.tostring` on it if it's an `Element`, `with_tail=False` avoids duplication of the tail.

You may need to handle other node types if they are present.

Comment: This could be written more compactly. Take this one-liner: `''.join(el if isinstance(el, str) else lxml.etree.tostring(el, with_tail=False) for el in doc.xpath('/review/text/node()'))`

Comment: You could probably just use `tostring` indiscriminately.

Comment: @Marcin: when I tried it, `tostring` complained that it couldn't serialize an `_ElementStringResult`

Answer (score 3):

That is considerably easy with [lxml](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)*, using the `parse()` and `tostring()` functions:

```
from  lxml.etree import parse, tostring
```

First you parse the doc and get your element (I am using XPath, but you can use whatever you want):

```
doc = parse('test.xml')
element = doc.xpath('//text')[0]
```

The `tostring()` function returns a text representation of your element:

```
>>> tostring(element)
'<text>Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>\n'
```

However, you do not want the external elements, so we can remove them with a simple `str.replace()` call:

```
>>> tostring(element).replace('<%s>'%element.tag, '', 1)
'Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>\n'
```

Note that `str.replace()` received 1 as the third parameter, so it will remove only the first occurrence of the opening tag. One can do it with the closing tag, too. Now, instead of 1, we pass -1 to replace:

```
>>> tostring(element).replace('</%s>'%element.tag, '', -1)
'<text>Some <text>text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.\n'
```

The solution, of course, is to do everything at once:

```
>>> tostring(element).replace('<%s>'%element.tag, '', 1).replace('</%s>'%element.tag, '', -1)
'Some <text>text with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.\n'
```

**EDIT**: @Charles made a good point: this code is fragile since the tag can have attributes. A possible yet still limited solution is to split the string at the first `>`:

```
>>> tostring(element).split('>', 1)
['<text',
 'Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>\n']
```

get the second resulting string:

```
>>> tostring(element).split('>', 1)[1]
'Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.</text>\n'
```

then rsplitting it:

```
>>> tostring(element).split('>', 1)[1].rsplit('</', 1)
['Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.', 'text>\n']
```

and finally getting the first result:

```
>>> tostring(element).split('>', 1)[1].rsplit('</', 1)[0]
'Some <text>text</text> with <extradata>data</extradata> in it.'
```

Nonetheless, this code is still fragile, since `>` is a perfectly valid char in XML, even inside attributes.

Anyway, I have to acknowledge that [MattH solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11123135/287976) is the real, general solution.

* Actually this solution works with [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), too, which is great if you do not want to depend upon lxml. The only difference is that you will have no way of using XPath.

Comment: The text replacement is adding quite a lot of fragility here. If your input file happens to have attributes on it? A namespace prefix?

Comment: I have the feeling that I won't gain much over pure regular expressions with this approach. Since the opening tag has at least one attribute it get's flaky too.

Comment: ``replace('</%s>'%element.tag, '', -1)`` should work, but I can't use ``.replace('<%s>'%element.tag, '', 1)`` because there are one or more attributes, so I have to use regex again (or something around ``content[content.index('>'):]``), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I like @Marcin's solution above, however I found that when using his 2nd option (converting a sub-node, not the root of the tree) it does not handle entities.

His code from above (modified to add an entity):

```
from lxml import etree
t = etree.XML("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<review>
  <title>Some testing stuff</title>
    <text>this &amp; that.</text>
</review>""")
e = t.xpath('//text')[0]
print (e.text + ''.join(map(etree.tostring, e))).strip()
```

returns:

```
this & that.
```

with a bare/unescaped '&' character instead of a proper entity ('&amp;').

My solution was to use to call etree.tostring at the node level (instead of on all children), then strip off the starting and ending tag using a regular expression:

```
import re
from lxml import etree
t = etree.XML("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<review>
  <title>Some testing stuff</title>
    <text>this &amp; that.</text>
</review>""")

e = t.xpath('//text')[0]
xml = etree.tostring(e)
inner = re.match('<[^>]*?>(.*)</[^>]*>\s*$', xml, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
print inner
```

produces:

```
this &amp; that.
```

I used re.DOTALL to ensure this works for XML containing newlines.

Answer (score -2):

Just found the solution, pretty easy:

```
In [31]: t = x.find('text')

In [32]: t
Out[32]: <Element text at 0xa87ed74>

In [33]: list(t.itertext())
Out[33]: ['Some text with ', 'data', ' in it.']

In [34]: ''.join(_)
Out[34]: 'Some text with data in it.'
```

`itertext` is definitly the way to go here!

Edit:// Sorry I thought you want only the text between the children, my bad

Comment: I can get the same - I think - with `x.find('text').get_text()`. **But** this approach excludes the inner tags and I need them.

Comment: This does not solve the OP problem in any way, actually. It is *required* to maintain the inner tags.

Comment: It does maintain the inner tags, just not more than one level, see my edit, `itertext` get's everything

Comment: Iterate over all children, not just the text.