# How to remove all attributes of a tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

How can I remove all the attributes of a xml tag so I can get from this:
`<xml blah blah blah>` to just `<xml>`.

With lxml I know I can remove the whole element and I didn't find any way to do it specific on a tag. (I found solutions on stackoverflow for C# but I want Python).

I am opening a gpx(xml) file and this is my code so far (based on [How do I get the whole content between two xml tags in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122397/how-do-i-get-the-whole-content-between-two-xml-tags-in-python)):

```
from lxml import etree

t = etree.parse("1.gpx")
e = t.xpath('//trk')[0]
print(e.text + ''.join(map(etree.tostring, e))).strip()
```

Another approach I did was this:

```
from lxml import etree

TOPOGRAFIX_NS = './/{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}'
TRACKPOINT_NS = TOPOGRAFIX_NS + 'extensions/{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1}TrackPointExtension/{http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1}'

doc1 = etree.parse("1.gpx")

for node1 in doc1.findall(TOPOGRAFIX_NS + 'trk'):
    node_to_string1 = etree.tostring(node1)
    print(node_to_string1)
```

But I get the trk tag with TOPOGRAFIX_NS attributes witch I don't want and here I am wanting to remove the tag attribute. I just want to get:

```
<trk> all the inside content </trk>
```

Thank you very much!

P.S. The content of the gpx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Endomondo.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <metadata>
    <author>
      <name>Blah Blah</name>
      <email id="blah" domain="blah.com"/>
    </author>
    <link href="http://www.endomondo.com">
      <text>Endomondo</text>
    </link>
    <time>2014-01-20T10:50:28Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Galati</name>
    <src>http://www.endomondo.com/</src>
    <link href="http://www.endomondo.com/workouts/260782567/13005122">
      <text>Galati</text>
    </link>
    <type>MOUNTAIN_BIKING</type>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="45.431074" lon="28.021038">
        <time>2013-10-20T05:49:04Z</time>
      </trkpt>

    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: This is actually about removing namespaces, not attributes. Namespace declarations look very much like attributes but they are different beasts.