# How to extract XML blocks with a given delimiter tag from large files?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have large (500 MB - 2 GB) XML files I currently process linearly with `iterparse`. The general structure is a lot of records with the same structure, of which I am interested in analyzing only a small subset. My approach today is to parse as I go and keep only the ones I am interested in (once they are parsed). This works, although slowly.

For various reasons (the main one being curiosity), I would like to rewrite the parsing to extract XML blocks meeting my definition of "record" (a set of specific tags) and check if the block (as a string) contains a specific substring which makes the record interesting. These blocks would be queued for further processing.

[The solutions to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122397/how-do-i-get-the-whole-content-between-two-xml-tags-in-python) all use DOM based approaches which are not suitable for my large files.

Is there an existing module/method which would take the boundary tag and spit out XML blocs delimited by it, in a linear fashion, something like the `xpath` method from `lxml.etree.parse`?

Comment: I show us a section of your file and required output. Would you be open to parsing the file in a tool of some kind or are you after a pure python code solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's not much I can do without knowing what criteria would define the nodes you're interested in.  But, I can try to answer part of the question anyway.

This should return a list of all of the elements of RecordTag or OtherTag.

```
records = etree.parse(file).xpath(".//*[self::RecordTag or self:OtherTag]")
```

If there is only one type of element you care about, then this xpath query is simpler, and probably gives better performance than the above, which performs self axis checks on every element in the tree.

```
xpath(".//Record")
```

If you have more complicated criteria for records you are interested in than just the tag, then I would need more details to help with constructing an xpath for that.