# How do I get all content between two html tags in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I try to extract all content (tags and text) from one main tag on html page. For example:

```
`my_html_page = '''
<html>
    <body>
       <div class="post_body">
          <span class="polor">
             <a class="p-color">Some text</a>
             <a class="p-color">another text</a>
          </span>
          <a class="p-color">hello world</a>
          <p id="bold">
              some text inside p
             <ul>
                <li class="list">one li</li>
                <li>second li</li>
             </ul>
         </p>
         some text 2
         <div>
             text inside div
         </div>
         some text 3
      </div>
      <div class="post_body">
          <a>text inside second main div</a>
      </div>
      <div class="post_body">
          <span>third div</span>
      </div>
      <div class="post_body">
          <p>four div</p>
      </div>
      <div class="post">
          other text
      </div>
  </body>
<html>'''`
```

And I need to get using xpath(`"(//div[@class="post_body"])[1]"`):

```
`
       <div class="post_body">
          <span class="polor">
             <a class="p-color">Some text</a>
             <a class="p-color">another text</a>
          </span>
          <a class="p-color">hello world</a>
          <p id="bold">
              some text inside p
             <ul>
                <li class="list">one li</li>
                <li>second li</li>
             </ul>
         </p>
         some text 2
         <div>
             text inside div
         </div>
         some text 3
      </div>
`
```

All inside tag `<div class="post_body">`

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122397/how-do-i-get-the-whole-content-between-two-xml-tags-in-python), but it did not help.

I need to create DOM by beautifulsoup parser in lxml.

```
 import lxml.html.soupparser
 import lxml.html
 text_inside_tag = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(my_html_page)
 text = text_inside_tag.xpath('(//div[@class="post_body"])[1]/text()')
```

And i can extract only text inside tag, but I need extract text with tags.

If i tried use this:

```
for elem in text.xpath("(//div[@class="post_body"])[1]/text()"):
   print lxml.html.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True)
```

I have error: `TypeError: Type '_ElementStringResult' cannot be serialized.`

Help, please.

Comment: Are you expecting only the text in output?

Comment: @Vilva No, I need text with tags in output.
`<htm>
   <body>
      <div> text text text</div>
   </body>
</html>`
I can extract: `text text text`
I need extract: `<div>text text text </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
import lxml.html.soupparser
import lxml.html

my_html_page = '''...some html markup here...'''
root = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(my_html_page)

for elem in root.xpath("//div[@class='post_body']"):
    result = elem.text + ''.join(lxml.html.tostring(e, pretty_print=True) for e in elem)
    print result
```

`result` variable constructed by combining text nodes within parent `<div>` with markup of all of the child nodes.

Comment: Invoking lxml is the best answer.